# Magento 2 - Getting order numbers by product id

Tags: magento2, product, orders

I want join order collection, order item collection and product collection. my goal is get all orders based product id.

example : my product_id is '123', and I want know all order number contain product_id '123'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found it,

this example my code, it will get order numbers based product id

```
....
protected $_order;
....
 public function __construct( 
    .....,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $order,
    ......
    )
   {
    ......
    $this->_order  = $order;
    ......
   }


 public function execute()
 {
  
    $orderCollection = $this->_order->create();
    
    $product_id = 123;
    $orderCollection->getSelect()
            ->join(
                'sales_order_item',
                'main_table.entity_id = sales_order_item.order_id'
            )->where('product_id = '.$product_id);

        $orderCollection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
        foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
            echo $order->getIncrementId() . ' <br/>';
        }
    }
```

Hope this help for someone in the next time.